# Adding A-Frame to Angular project

Tags: angular, node-modules, aframe

I want to add the A-Frame web framework to my Angular app.

I installed the node package by using `npm install --save aframe` and then I added the `"node_modules/aframe/dist/aframe.min.js"` on the test and build object of the `angular.json` file. When I try writting some A-frame code, it seems that angular does not recognize the custom A-frame elements. How can I fix this?

PS: I checked the `node_modules` folder and inside it, `aframe` is normally installed.

Comment: Can you show how you added it to module, components, etc?

Comment: I have added `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`